# Django 1.8.5 Migrations not migrating to Postgres database at all

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am having a strange problem. I am creating a simple table. The initial migration 0001 looks like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Customer',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('company_name', models.CharField(default=b'', unique=True, max_length=100)),
                ('address1', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=200)),
                ('address2', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=200, blank=True)),
                ('city', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=200)),
                ('state', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=100)),
                ('pincode', models.IntegerField(default=b'')),
                ('landline', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=15, blank=True)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(default=b'', max_length=254, blank=True)),
                ('website', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=100, blank=True)),
                ('contact1_first_name', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=100)),
                ('contact1_last_name', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=100)),
                ('contact1_mobile', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=15, blank=True)),
                ('contact1_email', models.EmailField(default=b'', max_length=254, blank=True)),
                ('contact2_first_name', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=100, blank=True)),
                ('contact2_last_name', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=100, blank=True)),
                ('contact2_mobile', models.CharField(default=b'', max_length=15, blank=True)),
                ('contact2_email', models.EmailField(default=b'', max_length=254, blank=True)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

I did makemigrations, i did migrate, i did syncdb. I get no errors, and absolutely no table is made in postgres sql. I had to make the table manually by doing sqlmigrate and posting the code into PGADMIN3. That did the trick and created the table.

However the whole point of using Django is that changes to the Model should be migrated over to the database and I should not have to change the model and the database separately, manually.

I have searched online and I dont see anyone else having a similar problem. Its a very basic issue, there are no errors and no changes to the database. What could the problem be?

Comment: You have to manually create a database first, then you have to do the migrations, then only tables will be created.

Comment: have you tried `python manage.py migrate <app> zero` and after that executing migration once again?

Comment: My database is already created. I will try Nhor's recommendation with the zero appended after the migrate command. I will revert with the outcome of this command. Could it be a permissions issue or a postgres sql issue? Its strange that i get no errors, and no change happens to the database.

Comment: That doesnt work. I tried doing squashmigrations and then removing all the other mgirations. That doesnt work either. At this stage, I would like to remove all migrations, and start from a fresh model which has all the changes i want in it? How can i do this?

Comment: I did the following 1) Deleted the migrations folder in my app 2) Using Pgadmin3 deleted the rows in the migrations table that mentioned myapp name. 3) I ran makemigrations, migrate and syncdb. I have my model in my db as I need it without any messy migrations in the middle. Do we really need migrations?

Answer (score 1):

When things are not working with the model and you want to start from scratch,what worked with me was

1. Make changes to your model to get it just right.
2. Delete all the migrations, by deleting the migrations folder in your app
3. In the database look for the migrations table (I used pgadmin3 as a front end for postgres sql) and delete rows that mention your app name
4. Run makemigrations appname, migrate and syncdb

And you have a fresh database exactly corresponding to your model, minus all the crud with migrations and all the small changes you made along the way, that you may not need to track.

Comment: same issue happening with me. I tried your solution as well, but nothing good happened. Can you suggest something else ?